# pyinstaller create onefile executable for windows issue

Tags: python, pyqt, exe, python-3.4, pyinstaller

My OS is Windows 10 (64bit OS). I use Python 3.4 (32bit version) and created a GUI using pyqt. I created a onefile .exe using this command:

```
python pyinstaller.py mygui1.py --onefile --noconsole
```

The produced executable is working fine on my system. However, when I execute the file on my 64bit Windows 7 PC (where I don't have python installed at all) I only see a grey surface. How can I make sure to include all dependencies so it will execute on any Windows 7/10 PC?

Comment: Possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548904/pyinstaller-error-with-pyqt-when-trying-to-build-onefile

Comment: Maybe the pyqt libraries aren't getting included by pyinstaller? I usually create a spec file and manually include the GUI toolkit. I'll dig up an example.

Comment: Strike that. I was thinking of when I used to use py2exe. My app uses PySide instead of PyQT and pyinstaller found it automatically. <shrugs>