# Python 3.5 + PyQt5 to standalone exe

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, pyqt5, nuitka

I'm new to coding and I need to transform my py file to an exe. I tried py2exe and it didn't work with python 3.5. Then I tried pyinstaller and it worked, but when I added PyQt5 to the program, pyinstaller also failed. I tried nuitka, and it builds the exe, but when I click on the exe file it shows a console for a few seconds and closes. I need an exe which shows a gui after being activated. Here are the modules that I used in the program:

```
import P4
import time
from datetime import datetime,date
import traceback
import os
import sys
import threading
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, QTimer
```

Error I get from nuitka exe file:
[image: error_0ne]

Error I get from pyinstaller exe file:

[image: Er2]

Dll's that pyinstaller needs:
[dlls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAAyx.jpg)

Comment: Can you run the .exe from the command line and post the error that you get?

Comment: @Repiklis of course, added pictures to the queastion field

Comment: I only have used PyQt4 with pyinstaller and not PyQt5, but you can try to modify your imports to `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui`, similar to the suggested PyQt4 [method (point 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8548950/3837382). This might work, but I think that it is most likely to have an issue with [the PyQt path](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2739585/3837382).

Comment: @Repiklis I tried, it doesn't help. I attached screenshot from pyinstaller, it says that programme can't find Qt5Core.dll and others dll's. Where i can add this files so pyinstaller could find them?

Comment: The best way (personal opinion) is to use a `.spec` file and use [this](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#adding-files-to-the-bundle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured out how to make an exe with Python 3.5 and pyinstaller. You need to install this:

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip --upgrade
```

Then add path to PyQt5 dll's. I used this:

```
pyinstaller -y --clean --paths C:\TEMP\env\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\bin\
```