# pyinstaller - ImportError: No module named Tkinter (all variants of decisions)

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pyinstaller

I use Python 2.7 Windows 8.

When I was faced with this problem, it is still not aware of how much it has pitfalls. Here I want to present all of the options that I have encountered and tested, as well as the option that I eventually helped.

1) I checked the spelling used by the module [Tkinter or tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25905540/importerror-no-module-named-tkinter).

2) I read about how to use the `pyinstaller`, when used in the project modules:`tkinter` and `matplotlib` then was able to give up`matplotlib`, but it also did not affect the solution to my problem.

3) Adds path to the module from the command line with the parameter `p` [PyInstaller -y -F --distpath="." -p "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk" test.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548904/pyinstaller-error-with-pyqt-when-trying-to-build-onefile?rq=1)

4) Connect only the necessary parts of the module https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/vtbKKt6v0is

5) Use pyinstaller option `--hiddenimport=Tkinter` and commented rows `excludedimports` in files `\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PIL.py` and `hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py` https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1584

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helped me to solve this problem:

1) Remove the `Python`.

2) Make a backup of the folder in which the remains were from `Python`.

3) Delete the folder in which you installed the `Python` (my problem is not solved without this item).

4) Install new `Python` and all the necessary modules.

Following these simple manipulations things started to work :)