# how to convert pyw to exe

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have installed pyinstaller like this `pip install pyinstaller` as a Youtube video said to convert pyw to exe.
Then the tutorial said to convert pyw to exe you need to type `pyinstaller -w filename.pyw`
, but this doesn't work for me why?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

`pyinstaller` is not a command on your system's PATH, which means that your terminal cannot find it. Because it is a Python module, you may be able to run it with `python -m pyinstaller -w main.pyw`. This `-m <name>` specifies that we wish to run a Python module with the given `name`.

Alternatively, you can add the location of the `pyinstaller` folder to your [PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-a-directory-to-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows). However, this requires finding out where `pyinstaller` was installed with `pip`, too. I've generally used the former strategy, and that's the strategy I recommend.

Comment: it says there is no module named pyinstaller

Comment: I would recommend looking over here, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740792/pyinstaller-no-module-named-pyinstaller. That should help

Comment: that doesnt help

Comment: iam trying to convert pyw to exe