# While installing pyinstaller, this occured : ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2]

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

When I try to install `pyinstaller` in windows machine through `pip` gives me the following error.

What I tried:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Error:

```
Installing collected packages: pyinstaller

  WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The 
system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\...\\Python310\\Scripts\\pyi-archive_viewer.exe' ->
'C:\\...\\Python310\\Scripts\\pyi-archive_viewer.exe.deleteme'
```

Comment: Please anyone help me figure out the solution for this problem.

Comment: When I try this command ' pip install pyinstaller ' in some other pc it works fine, but in mine says the above error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem "*Requirement already satisfied*" with the Pillow module. I saw it in IDE, but it was broken. So I deleted the package folder in `C:\Python310\Lib\site-packages` and reinstalled it. You could try to do the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my problem is solved with this answer -->https://stackoverflow.com/a/48337959/17518541

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python311\Scripts\pyi-archive_viewer.exe' -> 'C:\Python311\Scripts\pyi-archive_viewer.exe.deleteme'

Just keep running `pip install pyinstaller` multiple times... It will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35741434)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by uninstallation of partially installed  pyinstaller. Then I installed it as Administrator.

Comment: @ArkistarvhKltzuonstev This isn't an "I'm having this problem, too" comment, it's an actual answer. Even though the answerer starts by saying that they had the same issue, they continue by explaining how they solved it.